# Calculate special function by conditional FunctionExpand

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions, algebraic-manipulation

I want to calculate an expression with *[Whittaker's W](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhittakerW.html)* function
$$f(z)=\sum _{v,k=0}^{\infty } z^{\frac{k+v}{2}} W\left(\frac{k-v}{2},- \frac{k+v+1}{2},z\right),\tag{1}$$
however for some input combinations MMA reports no result, although the function value exists. An example where MMA fails is $v=k=1,z=0$.

```
v = 1; k = 1; z = 0;
z^((k+v)/2) WhittakerW[(k-v)/2,-(v+k+1)/2,z]
(* Indeterminate *)
```

We understand this if we have a look at the two factors

$z^{\frac{k+v}{2}}= z=0\tag{2}$
and
$W\left(\frac{k-v}{2},- \frac{k+v+1}{2},z\right) =W\left(0,- \frac{3}{2},z\right)=e^{-\frac{z}{2}} \left(\frac{2}{z}+1\right)=\left(\frac{2}{0}+1\right), \tag{3}$

where we have used that `FunctionExpand[`$W\left(0,- \frac{3}{2},z\right)$`]`$=e^{-\frac{z}{2}} \left(\frac{2}{z}+1\right) $.
The division by zero in eq.(3) produces an undefined result.  The correct way would be first to evaluate the product of eq.(2) and (3) and then insert the value for $z$.
$$z e^{-\frac{z}{2}} \left(\frac{2}{z}+1\right)=e^{-\frac{z}{2}} \left(2+z\right)=e^{-\frac{0}{2}} \left(2+0\right)=2\tag{4}$$

This we get in MMA by

```
v = 1; k = 1; Clear[z];
Simplify[FunctionExpand[z^((k+v)/2) WhittakerW[(k-v)/2,-(v+k+1)/2,z]]] /. z->0
(* 2 *)
```

`Simplify` and `FunctionExpand` always lead to the correct result, but enormously increase calculation time. For most cases eq.(1) could be calculated faster by the first code snippet and only sometimes the second slower code is necessary.

How to achieve  that MMA expands and simplifies only if necessary? Are there other solutions that do not rely on transformation like `FunctionExpand` or `Simplify` and instead use a function that always works?

MMA 13

Comment: Since the problem arises only for z = 0, treat this case separately with Piecewise.

Comment: For $z=0$ we get polynomials of degree $k$.